# How do I display all URLs in a redirect chain?

Tags: wget, curl

I'm looking for a way to show all of the URLs in a redirect chain, preferably from the shell. I've found a way to almost do it with curl, but it only shows the first and last URL. I'd like to see all of them.

There must be a way to do this simply, but I can't for the life of me find what it is.

Edit: Since submitting this I've found out how to do it with Chrome (CTRL+SHIFT+I->Network tab). But, I'd still like to know how it can be done from the Linux command line.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

How about simply using `wget`?

```
$ wget http://picasaweb.google.com 2>&1 | grep Location:
Location: /home [following]
Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpicasaweb.google.com%252Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true [following]
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true [following]
```

`curl -v` also shows some info, but looks not as useful as `wget`.

```
$ curl -v -L http://picasaweb.google.com 2>&1 | egrep "^> (Host:|GET)"
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: picasaweb.google.com
> GET /home HTTP/1.1
> Host: picasaweb.google.com
> GET /accounts/ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpicasaweb.google.com%252Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com
> GET /ServiceLogin?hl=en_US&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Flh%2Flogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fpicasaweb.google.com%252Fhome&service=lh2&ltmpl=gp&passive=true HTTP/1.1
> Host: accounts.google.com
```

Comment: That looks like it'll do it. I'm just curious though, why did you send STDERR to STDOUT?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it will only work for redirection using the location header, not for 301 http codes

Comment: I cannot reproduce the wget example. Returns "503: Service Unavailable." - Maybe they are blocking the wget but not the curl http-user-agent? Is this just me?

Comment: When I have a redirect from `www` to the canonical URL, a bit later I have redirect from HTTP to HTTPS or otherwise. How can I collect an array of all redirects per domain? Was it the point of a question?

Comment: wget and curl both fail for this link: https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/reconciliation/no-index-used-as-key

Comment: As an aside, `... |& grep ...` accomplishes the same thing as `... 2>&1 | grep ...`, and is much easier to remember and type out.

Answer (score 5):

### A proper curl-based solution

```
url=https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
while redirect_url=$(
  curl -I -s -S -f -w "%{redirect_url}\n" -o /dev/null "$url"
); do
  echo "$url"
  url=$redirect_url
  [[ -z "$url" ]] && break
done
```

*Result:*

```
https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
https://t.co/BAvVoPyqNr
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

This is 12% faster than my [wget-based solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680574).

### Benchmark details

```
cd "$(mktemp -d)"

cat <<'EOF' >curl-based-solution
#!/bin/bash
url=https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
while redirect_url=$(
  curl -I -s -S -f -w "%{redirect_url}\n" -o /dev/null "$url"
); do
  echo "$url"
  url=$redirect_url
  [[ -z "$url" ]] && break
done
EOF
chmod +x curl-based-solution

cat <<'EOF' >wget-based-solution
#!/bin/bash
url=https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
wget -S --spider "$url" 2>&1 \
 | grep -oP '^--[[:digit:]: -]{19}--  \K.*'
EOF
chmod +x wget-based-solution

hyperfine --warmup 5 ./wget-based-solution ./curl-based-solution
```

```
$ hyperfine --warmup 5 ./wget-based-solution ./curl-based-solution
Benchmark #1: ./wget-based-solution
  Time (mean ± σ):      1.397 s ±  0.025 s    [User: 90.3 ms, System: 19.7 ms]
  Range (min … max):    1.365 s …  1.456 s    10 runs
 
Benchmark #2: ./curl-based-solution
  Time (mean ± σ):      1.250 s ±  0.015 s    [User: 72.4 ms, System: 23.4 ms]
  Range (min … max):    1.229 s …  1.277 s    10 runs
 
Summary
  './curl-based-solution' ran
    1.12 ± 0.02 times faster than './wget-based-solution'
```

Answer (score 4):

To show *all* of the URLs in a redirect chain, including the first:

```
wget -S --spider https://rb.gy/x7cg8r 2>&1 \
 | grep -oP '^--[[:digit:]: -]{19}--  \K.*'
```

*Result (tested on Fedora Linux):*

```
https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
https://t.co/BAvVoPyqNr
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

**wget options used:**

```
-S
--server-response

    Print the headers sent by HTTP servers and responses sent by FTP servers.

--spider

    When invoked with this option, Wget will behave as a Web spider, which
    means that it will not download the pages, just check that they are there
    ...
```

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.mankier.com/1/wget</sup></sup>

The [combination](https://superuser.com/a/197043) of `-S` and `--spider` causes `wget` to issue `HEAD` requests instead of `GET` requests.

**GNU grep options used:**

```
-o
--only-matching

    Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such
    part on a separate output line.

-P
--perl-regexp

    Interpret PATTERNS as Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCREs).
```

<sup><sup>Source: https://www.mankier.com/1/grep</sup></sup>

The lines we are interested in look like this:

```
--2021-12-07 12:29:25--  https://rb.gy/x7cg8r
```

You see that the timestamp consists of 19 characters comprised of digits, hyphens,  colons, and spaces. It is therefore matched by `[[:digit:]-: ]{19}`, where we used a [fixed quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) of 19.

The `\K` [resets the start of the matched portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247812/how-to-use-grep-to-get-anything-just-after-name#comment85323444_1247824).

**Swap grep with sed**

The `grep` pipeline stage may be replaced with `sed`, if you prefer:

```
wget -S --spider https://rb.gy/x7cg8r 2>&1 \
 | sed -En 's/^--[[:digit:]: -]{19}--  (.*)/\1/p'
```

### Compared to the `curl`-based solution...

The curl-based solution omits the first url in the redirect chain:

```
$ curl -v -L https://rb.gy/x7cg8r 2>&1 | grep -i "^< location:"
< Location: https://t.co/BAvVoPyqNr
< location: https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

Furthermore, it incurs a 4354.99% increase in bytes sent to second pipeline stage:

```
$ wget -S --spider https://rb.gy/x7cg8r 2>&1 | wc -c
2728

$ curl -v -L https://rb.gy/x7cg8r 2>&1 | wc -c
121532

$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n", (121532-2728)/2728*100}'
4354.99
```

In my benchmarking, the wget solution was slightly (4%) faster than the curl-based solution.

**Update:** See [my curl-based answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/680583) for fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

`curl -v` can show all the URLs in an HTTP redirect chain:

```
$ curl -v -L https://go.usa.gov/W3H 2>&1 | grep -i "^< location:"
< location: http://hurricanes.gov/nhc_storms.shtml
< Location: https://www.hurricanes.gov/nhc_storms.shtml
< location: https://www.nhc.noaa.gov:443/nhc_storms.shtml
< location: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/cyclones
< Location: https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/cyclones
< location: http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/cyclones/
< Location: https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/cyclones/
```